# PHP running java jar files with parameters as php variables

Tags: java, php, html, jar

Hi I am attempting to execute a jar from PHP 5

Here is the code I am executing:

```
$command = '"java -jar WEB-INF\\lib\\FileReceiver.jar '.$address.' '.$service_port.' \"'.$command.'\" \"'.$filePath.'\""';
exec($command, $out);
```

But the jar is not being executed. 
I had logged the $command variable in firebug and took the output and inserted into the code such as:

```
exec("java -jar WEB-INF\lib\FileReceiver.jar 127.0.1.1 2018 \"docs/document.txt \" \"C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.26\\webapps\\test\\downloads\\doument.txt\"", $out);
```

gives the correct output. I dont understand why hard coding it works but the variable which contains the same information does not.

Could someone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure `$adress` `$service_port` `$command` and `$filepath` have the right values?

Comment: you need to show \" , you should write \\"

Comment: @Shingetsu yes I am sure, I literally copied whats in the variable $command from firePHP console and pasted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
$command = escapeshellarg($address).' '.escapeshellarg($service_port).' '.escapeshellarg($command).' '.escapeshellarg($filePath).' ';

exec('java -jar WEB-INF\\lib\\FileReceiver.jar '.$command, $out);
```

Comment: same issue if I hard code what is contained in the variable its worksm but if I pass the variable, the jar is not executing. Thank you for your quick reply. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I tried it and the result is correct. I replaced $command with the echo result in exec and it works correctly. I am totally confused why having the variable in the exec will not execute.

Comment: @ßee , try with escapeshellarg

Comment: I tired that too nothing...it just adds a space after the double quotes at the beginning and end and removed the quotes in the middle which would make it worse. Either way the jar did not execute

Comment: Tried the encapsulating each component like you did above but nothing, the jar is not even being run. I even tried surrounding the entire command in quotes like exec('"java -jar WEB-INF\\lib\\FileReceiver.jar '.$command.'"', $out); with no success

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I just figured out the problem. the $command had a \n character which stopped it from executing in the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You're over-escaping the double quotes in your first snippet.

You're using single quotes for the literal string delimiter, so you don't need to escape the double quote.

Also, the final `'\""'` should be `'"'`