# PHP Exec is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, exec

I am trying to execute a .jar file from PHP. This is the code

```
$data = $cardnumber."|".$cvv."|".$expyear."|".$expmonth;
        $javacommand = "java -jar atomintegration.jar "."\"".$data."\"";
        echo "Command: ",$javacommand,"<br>";   
        exec($javacommand, $output);
        echo "Encrypted data: ",$output[0],"<br>";
```

It is just not working. Im using codeigniter. This function code is inside a library and the .jar file is also in the same dir as that of the library.

I tried running it from putty/shell it was executing.

In the code the `exec` is not working.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is the error output?

Comment: How can I see that ? There is no error being shown.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If you are using PHP 5.3.0 or less and safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir

Comment: you can enable error reporting http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125/670623

Comment: This is turned on , but im not getting any errors.

Comment: do you have to try to exec `java -version`?  could it print the output?
if not, i think it's path problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP running java jar files with parameters as php variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004196/php-running-java-jar-files-with-parameters-as-php-variables)

Comment: Its printing the path and output of java version.. also my safe mode is off

Comment: can you try `exec('$javacommand 2>&1', $output); print_r($output);` to see what is response of your command.